# Excel Live linked files imported into Access as Short Text Data Type Instead of Number Data Type

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am importing sheets from the same workbook in excel into Access. The data that I'm importing is set as a number for all sheets. Most sheets import as a Number Data Type for the imported field, but some are importing as a Short Text Data Type no matter if its set as a number field. I need to know what I can do to fix this since I cannot change the data type in access for the Imported Live Linked Excel Sheet.

Thank you,

Comment: If the data was in the column before it was formatted as a number then it is possible some holdover formatting exists.  I recommend using `text to columns` to ensure that formatting is completely pushed through.

Answer (score 1):

Don't import the sheet, but link it. Then create a simpel select query with the linked table as source and where you convert and clean up the data.

Now, use this query for importing to the final table or your further processing.

Comment: I am currently Linking the spreadsheet instead of importing. I have to do this for over 100 Sheets so having to create an additional query seems tedious.

Comment: Im not sure how I could automate that process to be honest.